# Is there a performance hit between code in my view and code that I call in with @Html.Partial?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have ten or more view where I could use this:

```
@Html.Partial("_Stats")
```

or:

20-30 lines of HTML code in my every view.

Does the @Html.Partial() bring in code at compile or run time? If at run time then is there a performance overhead for rendering the partial and should I bother about it ?

Comment: Get a profiler, measure the performance of your application, and let the profiler tell you what part is slow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `@{Html.RenderPartial("_Stats");}`, it works faster.

Comment: Can you explain the difference. I didn't know about this.

Comment: There is no difference between @Html. and @{Html. } apart from notation

Comment: Thanks for down voting. [Html.Partial vs Html.RenderPartial & Html.Action vs Html.RenderAction](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5248183/html-partial-vs-html-renderpartial-html-action-vs-html-renderaction). Also look at [ASP MVC Compile-time include of partial view](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8920250/asp-mvc-compile-time-include-of-partial-view)

Comment: Your links are talking about Partial vs RenderPartials and don't provide any evidence that RenderPartials will be quicker, only suggestion from Darin. And in fact, Html.Partial is just a wrapper for Html.RenderPartial.

Comment: Try to make benchmark yourself and you will see difference. Question is taking about more then ten partials. With rising of partial count you will better results. I also agree with this article: [ASP.NET MVC - Html.Partial vs Html.RenderPartial](http://info.titodotnet.com/2011/10/aspnet-mvc-htmlpartial-vs.html) "RenderPartial is a bit faster"

Answer (score 1):

[Premature](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?PrematureOptimization) [optimisation is a root](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/80084/is-premature-optimization-really-the-root-of-all-evil) [of all evil](http://shreevatsa.wordpress.com/2008/05/16/premature-optimization-is-the-root-of-all-evil/)!! Do use partials as you pleased, don't worry about the performance just yet. Worry about it when your app halts with million hits a day. Probably one request to DB costs more than a few partials includes.