# How to use @RenderPage to include CSS content inline - MVC Razor

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc, razor

I am currently exporting a page from my project into Excel which will not allow the linking of external content e.g. external CSS.

What I am trying to achieve is a simple way to include a CSS file in my `view` but to have it called directly from a CSS file which will have automatically been minified by Visual Studio.

So, in my view I have tried this:

```
<style type="text/css">
   @RenderPage("~/CSS/_ExportStyles.min.css")
</style>
```

but doing this returns the following error:

> Server Error in '/' Application.
>
> The following file could not be rendered because its extension ".css"
>   might not be supported: "~/CSS/_ExportStyles.min.css".

What I know will work would be to place the CSS in a normal `.cshtml` file and include that, but I would lose the ability to `".min"` the file which keeps the file size small and allows me to automatically strip out comments etc.

Comment: Does @Styles.Render("~/CSS/_ExportStyles.min.css") not work?

Comment: I'm afraid not @markpsmith that will add a link to the file and not include the contents inline. When you open the Export, you get the error message `Problems During Load - Missing file:C:\CSS\_ExportStyles.min.css`

Comment: Does it work if you put the css file in that location, i.e. C:\CSS\

Comment: It would do, but `C:\` is on my local machine... the problem is that once the file is exported, it looks for the CSS on the local machine and not the remote server. I could use a full file path but I don't want the CSS files getting pulled from the server, I wanted them to be self contained and not dependent on an internet connection.

Comment: [This might help](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14298604/how-to-include-css-styles-inline-in-razor-view) - The second answer demostrates an extension allowing you to embed the css instead of linking to it.

Comment: Thank you for that! looking deeper I found this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5314476/how-do-you-include-html-or-asp-file-using-razor/5317313 and found this in one of the answers. `@Html.Raw(File.ReadAllText(Server.MapPath("~/CSS/_ExportStyles.min.css")))`

Answer (score 21, accepted):

So, it turns out that `@RenderPage` is not what I was looking for...

what I needed is this:

`@Html.Raw(File.ReadAllText(Server.MapPath("~/CSS/_ExportStyles.min.css")))`

Comment: So, file is re-read from disk with every request?

Comment: Although this works, it's a bad idea for performance.