# mvc3 how to create a resuable dropdownlist

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, html-select

I am learning new things about C#.net and Razor everyday but efficiency has now come up. I have a dropdownlist that is being used on 5 different pages with the exact same options how can I create just 1 and then reuse it across the other pages ? So that I only have to make a change in 1 in order to affect the rest, I been wrestling with this issue for the last couple of hours.

**Page 1**

```
<select name="myList" id="myList">
<option>Cars</option>
<option>Van</option>
<option>Motorcycle</option>
</select>
```

That's the list I would like to clone.

Answer (score 0):

I think this thread has some answers that may steer you in the right direction.

[How do you include .html or .asp file using razor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5314476/how-do-you-include-html-or-asp-file-using-razor)

Answer (score 0):

I would say the answer depends on what you're doing with the dropdown value on postback. You could use RenderAction to return a string in your view if you don't want to make the data for your dropdown part of the models you're passing to your views, but then what do you do with it?

Comment: Yes the dropdown is a part of the model that i'm dropping inside the view.

Answer (score 0):

Create partial view which accept one model as argument. Pass list of select option  through this model

use `@Html.Partial("_drpDownView",model)`  call this on every page use passed model containing list as parameter for select options